# How to make features portable in Codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I am working on a CRM application in Codeigniter, Currently I am using standard method for creating its features(means controllers and models views etc). I want to make upcoming features like portable plugins works like in Wordpress. means I want to give the features to the customers according to the their requirements. so I can enable/disable app features(and functionality/code of every module remains separate) with less effort.

How can i achieve that in codeigniter?

Comment: anyone here to reply?

Comment: this question can't be answered here - beside the fact that wp is open source - so you can take a look into without any restrictions and try to port that over to your application, the only help i can give you - take a look @https://bitbucket.org/wiredesignz/codeigniter-modular-extensions-hmvc, maybe it helps